# swift correct syntax if else while etc

Tags: swift, syntax, sprite-kit

I have a SKSpritenode which can be dragged around the screen, within a boundary.
I have a test for being within the boundary.

```
if backgroundRect.contains(paddleRect){
    let paddleX = paddle.position.x + (touchLocation.x - previousLocation.x)
    let paddleY = paddle.position.y + (touchLocation.y - previousLocation.y)
    paddle.position = CGPoint(x: paddleX, y: paddleY)
} else {
    print ("paddleRect not contained by backgroundRect")
}
```

At the moment I can drag the paddle around within the background. When I drag the paddle and it hits the edge of the background then it isn't contained within the background and stops so I can't move it anymore.

I would like be able to move it just within the background rectangle but not stop responding to drags at the edge. I know "if else" isn't the correct way to do this, but am wondering how I write it so the paddle keeps moving, within the bounds of the background rectangle.

Is it a "while continue" loop? or something else?

Comment: perhaps you meant `intersects` instead of `contains`?

Comment: that part of the code is doing the testing so is what i need to happen.ie the paddle is restricted to inside the background.

Comment: even if it was intersects i have the same problem, its just the code that deals with what happens when the test returns false i need to change... at the moment with an if else statement its stops dead, but i still need to be able to drag the paddle back into the rectangle away from the edge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that once you exit the rectangle, you lose the ability to change the position of the paddle. Because of that, every subsequent check of `backgroundRect.contains(paddleRect)` will return `false`, forever.

What you should do instead is always compute the potential position, and either use it, or discard it:

```
let potentialPosition = CGPoint(
    x: paddle.position.x + (touchLocation.x - previousLocation.x),
    y: paddle.position.y + (touchLocation.y - previousLocation.y)
)

// This line is approximated, I don't know the exact relation between
// `paddleRect` and `paddle`, but you get the idea
if backgroundRect.contains(potentialPosition) {
    paddle.position = potentialPosition
} else {
    print ("paddleRect not contained by backgroundRect")
}
```

Comment: @pjs You're welcome to edit answers, especially for little typos like that. The OP will be notified, and can just to keep/reject your change. I fixed this one myself, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: the solution worked. I changed the potentialPosition to a potentialRect for more accuracy so it detected the edges rather than the centre point.